# (If exists) a set of all ordinals that set is an ordinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

In set theory (ZF) an ordinal is a transitive set of transitive sets. Thus
(if exists) a set of all ordinals gives a contradiction therefore there is
no set of all ordinals.

But what is wrong with the following:
An ordinal is not only a transitive set of transitive sets, but *also*
an ordinal is a limit ordinal *or* there is a 'greatest' ordinal belonging to
that ordinal, but not both.

Thus, (if exists) a set of all ordinals then that set is not a limit-ordinal
      otherwise the successor of that limit-ordinal gives a contradiction,
therefore 
      if the set of all ordinals exists and is an ordinal then there is a 'greatest'
      ordinal belonging to that set of all ordinals,
      but that is impossible because there is no 'greatest' ordinal.

Therefore if exists a set of all ordinals then that set is *not* an ordinal.

Thank you for your attention, Doeko Homan

Comment: This is called the [Burali-Forti paradox](http://enwp.org/Burali-Forti_Paradox).

Comment: "An ordinal is a transitive set of transitive sets" not quite; its a hereditarily transitive set. This basically means "transitivity all the way down."

Answer (score 5):

This proof is okay. It could use cleanup, but its mathematical essence is okay.

The usual, somewhat simpler proof that the collection of all ordinals is not an ordinal. Simply because then $\sf Ord\in Ord$, and this just contradicts the fact that $\in$ well-ordered the ordinals.

Really what you are proving (or should be proving) is that if $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then $\alpha+1$ exists, and that a transitive set of ordinals is an ordinal; and that if $\sf Ord$ is a set, then it is the largest ordinal.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Indeed, a transitive set of ordinals

Comment: The set of all ordinals is not an ordinal. It is not an ordinal because it is not a limit-ordinal, or there is no `greatest' ordinal belonging to the set of all ordinals. Therefore we can postulate the set of all ordinals.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to say in this comment.

Comment: For every ordinal \alpha \neq 0 , \alpha is a limit ordinal or \bigcup \alpha is the greatest ordinal belonging to \alpha.  But the set of all ordinals **Ord** is not a limit ordinal and there is no greatest ordinal belonging to **Ord**. Therefore **Ord** is not an ordinal.

Comment: Compare with the set of all natural numbers $\omega$. For every natural number > 0 there is a greatest natural number belonging to that number. But to the set of all natural numbers belongs no greatest natural number. Therefore the set of all natural numbers is not a natural number.

Comment: Again this can be simplified a bit, by noting that there is no last ordinal, so $\sf Ord$ must be a limit ordinal, if it's an ordinal, but then it has a successor which is not an ordinal at all.

Comment: Thank you again for the helpful comments. Let me formulate my conclusion. The set of all ordinals **Ord** is not an ordinal. Therefore we can postulate the set **Ord** of all ordinals without getting the contradiction **Ord** $\in$ **Ord**.

Comment: You mean class of all ordinals, not set of all ordinals. If it were a set, then it was an ordinal.